# Extjs Datefield without a datepicker on a side

Tags: javascript, extjs, datepicker

I have a Datefield in extjs and has following configuration:

```
xtype: 'datefield',
            emptyText: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            validateOnBlur: false,
            validateOnChange: false,
            width: ifNull(uiConfig.inputWidth, 120),
            hideTrigger: this.question.unknownField,
            maxValue: new Date(),
            listeners:{
                blur:{fn:this.onBlur, scope: this},
                focus: function() {
                    if(me.controls.dateUnknown)
                        me.controls.dateUnknown.setValue(false);
```

I wanted to have this dateField but without the DatePicker in the side.

Comment: what do you mean "without the DatePicker in the side"? You don't want any picker? It's not located where you want it? You don't want the trigger button? Please be specific.

Comment: Yes I dont want the picker.

Comment: If you don't want the picker, use a text field with [Mask](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-maskRe) and custom validations. See [Ext.form.field.Text](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text) api documentation for details

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that as well. The Specification doesn't allow me to use text field. I was hoping something like `hideTrigger:true` would work but it didn't.

Comment: You can't do that with a simple config. You could always prevent the expand or the 'down' key events... But the best is probably to use a TextField instead of a DateField.

Comment: yeah, Thanks for the Suugestion. I Think textfield with Mask would be the best option.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following much simpler than the textfield customisation route:

```
{
 xtype: 'datefield',
 format: 'd-M-Y',
 hideTrigger: true,
 onDownArrow: Ext.emptyFn
}
```

(The "onDownArrow" override is to stop the picker from appearing when down arrow is pressed in the field)

Answer (score 0):

hideTrigger:true works to hide the picker and display only the underlying textfield

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Date-cfg-hideTrigger

Answer (score 0):

in Ext JS 7.0.0

```
{
 xtype: 'datefield',
 format: 'd-M-Y',

 readOnly: true
}
```

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Date.html

> readOnly : Boolean BINDABLE true to prevent the user from changing the
> field, and hide all triggers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).